# 2D Gaussian Curve_fit with flawed data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've been trying to fit a 2D Gaussian on my data. I have a (x,y) map and a z value for each coordinate. However, i want to get rid of some z values but since curve_fit asks for an array as (x,y) arguments, it has been hard to get rid of correspondent (x,y) values in the (x,y) array.

I've seen there are many solutions (masked array, lmfit) but i chose a simpler one as i'm not really good with python.

Here is my code :

```
def gaussienne(Var, xo, yo, backgr, gx, gy, theta):
    
    x,y = Var
    
    a = np.cos(theta)**2/(2*gx**2) + np.sin(theta)**2/(2*gy**2)
    b = -np.sin(2*theta)/(4*gx**2) + np.sin(2*theta)/(4*gy**2)
    c = np.sin(theta)**2/(2*gx**2) + np.cos(theta)**2/(2*gy**2)
    
    res=backgr+np.exp(-(a*(x-xo)**2 + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo)+ c*(y-yo)**2))
    
    return res.ravel() 

x=np.linspace(start_x,start_x+(taille_x)*step_x, taille_x)
y=np.linspace(start_y,start_y+(taille_y)*step_y, taille_y)
mask=[]

intensite=intensite.reshape(taille_x, taille_y)
for i in range(taille_x):
     for j in range (taille_y):
         if intensite[i,j]!=0:
               mask.append([x[i],y[j],intensite[i,j]])
mask=np.array(mask)

p0 = a, b, 80, 0.2, 0.2, 0.001
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussienne, mask[:,:2], mask[:,2], p0, maxfev=5000)
```

Basically, for every z value that i want to take (ie not equal to 0), i add to mask the z value and correspondent (x,y) coordinates. Mask is then a list of tuples. I turn it into an array and give it to curve_fit.

Then i get the error : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I don't understand how i get this error since mask[:,:2] is (2,n) and mask[:,2] is (1,n)

Thanks for your help

Comment: start_x, start_y, taille_x, taille_y, step_x, step_y = ?

Comment: I get these values from another function. x and y don't always have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how i get this error since mask[:,:2] is (2,n)

Not quite - `mask[:, :2].shape` is `(n, 2)`, so it has to be `x, y = Var.T` - or of course you can pass `mask[:, :2].T` to `curve_fit()`.

Comment: That was that simple.. Thanks a lot!